# Mirror iPad Pro to MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, display, screen-capture, mirroring

I use the PDF Expert app on iPad Pro to annotate documents using the Apple Pencil, and it works brilliantly. Now, I'd like to mirror the same work flow to my MacBook Air (so I can still look straight down at my iPad, which makes annotation easy), and ideally, run a screen capture program on my MacBook Air.

Two primary questions: 1) how do I most efficiently mirror (app suggestions), and 2) is there a way to run a screen capture program or any program that would accomplish the same thing on my laptop if I'm using my laptop as a mirror?

Thanks ahead of time. I open to any suggestions outside what I've proposed. Essentially, I need a way to screen capture (video) my iPad Pro workflow.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  These are two very good questions, however, they should be split up as two separate questions. See [Multiple Part Questions](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/multiple-part-questions) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you connect your iPad to your computer, you can natively display and record the iPad's screen on the Mac, answering both your questions at once, if I understand you correctly.

1. Connect the iPad to the computer and open QuickTime Player.
2. Select File > New Movie Recording (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)
3. Click the dropdown arrow to the right of the record button and select your iPad's name from the list. (see below—“Seagull” is the name of mine)
4. If you want to record the screen, simply press the record button.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use an app called Duet Display. It's very good and works very smoothly.

Comment: Will that allow me to use a native screen capture program (on MacBook Air) to record my iPad workflow though?

Comment: Duet work the other direction, it extends the screen on your mac to the iPad, not the other way around. So you cannot use duet here.